# Column space of $A^*$ is row space of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, adjoint-operators

I have seen that range $A^*$ = $(\text{null }A)^\perp$, for example [here](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-null-space-and-range-of-the-adjoint-of-a-linear-map). And I have seen that $(\text{null A})^\perp$ = row $A$, for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_spaces#:%7E:text=It%20follows%20that%20the%20null,theorem%20(see%20dimension%20above).). Does it therefore follow that range $A^*$ = row $A$? I haven't seen this written anywhere, and it seems like such a simple relationship that, if it were true, it would pop up on the internet somewhere. So what am I missing? Or is it just true?

Comment: Does $A$ denote a linear transformation or a matrix ?

Comment: $A$ denotes a matrix.

Comment: So $A^*$ is the transpose of $A$ ?

Comment: Well, the conjugate transpose of $A$, right? I think it's obviously true if $A$ is a real matrix, in which case $A^* = A^T$. It would be surprising to me if it were also necessarily true for matrices with complex entries, because in that case $A^T \neq A^*$.

Comment: @1Teaches2Learn In the second link, the article is specifically concerned with **real** matrices, as is noted in the introductory blurb. In general, I have only seen "row spaces" referred to in the context of real matrices.